# How to combine arrays or images of size 128x128 in python

Tags: image, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have 'n' grayscale images/arrays of 128x128 and I want to join them to get array of size 128x128xn.
I have tried several approaches but I can get nx128x128.
For example

```
a1 = np.random.rand(128,128)
a2 = np.random.rand(128,128)
b1 = np.random.rand(128,128)
b2 = np.random.rand(128,128)
c1 = np.random.rand(128,128)
c2 =np.random.rand(128,128)

X1 = [a1, a2]


X2 = [b1, b2]

X3 = [c1, c2]

X = [X1, X2, X3]

X = np.array(X)
X.shape
```

I'm getting final shape as (3, 2, 128, 128)

but I'm interested in 3x128x128x2

please help how can I get this.

Comment: Do you mean you have a **list** of 128x128 arrays, or `arrayA` and `arrayB` both of shape 128x128 or do you mean something else. Please show a minimal, runnable example. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes both have size of 128x128. I want to combine them to make 128x128x2.
afterwards, I have 10 such sets having 128x128x2 each. I want to combine all 10 to make 10x128x128x2

Comment: No, please click `edit` under your question and add enough runnable code to create a minimal example of your specific scenario - that's how StackOverflow works. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [np.moveaxis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) to move the second axis to the last:

```
interesting = np.moveaxis(X, 1, -1)
```